# Clear fix ie8 and CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, clearfix

Been making a website to try learn a bit more css and html.

Thought it was going well till I tried to show it to someone in IE (I use ff)

When I loaded the page up the footer seemed it to in the wrong place and i can't figure out why
Here is a screen shot http://www.flickr.com/photos/mattcripps/8300226269/

You can see the code for the website here 
http://www.deltacars.co.uk/testsite/

Any help would be great as this is doing mt head in.

Comment: Code can be seen by going to the link I gave.

Comment: What version of IE?
<footer> is a html5 tag not supported in older versions.
You have to use something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to get around it.

Comment: Ie 8. How do I use modernizr?

Comment: You can find good information in [their documentation](http://modernizr.com/docs/).
But all you have to do really is link the script in your html file.

Comment: Check out the html5 boilerplate - http://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<footer>` is a html5 tag. It's not supported in Internet Explorer 8 or lower. You can use a javascript library [shim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_%28computing%29) like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to get around it.

Comment: have managed to get the footer in the correct position but the page wrap background color which is white is not going the full length of the page. any idea why?

Comment: It's because the footer is outside of the wrapper. 
And the footer has a margin-bottom of 10px, which makes the body background show below.
My suggestion is to just remove the margin-bottom from the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bring the footer inside page-wrap div.That will solve the issue. Also add *clear:left;* to footer css.

Comment: i have moved the footer into the page wrap div but this has made no difference